# Arrange by value, only if other conditions are satifisfied

Tags: r, sorting

```
df = tibble(id = letters[1:3],
              some_time = c(3,1,2),
              is_x = c(1,0,1),
              is_y = c(0,1,0)
              )
```

I have a df where the goal is to find the correct arrangement of rows, such that the id with the latest possible time is in the 3rd row, only if, for the first row is_x == 1 is TRUE, and is_y == 1 is TRUE for the second row.

For example, the df above is in a correct order, but

```
df %>%
    arrange(some_time)
```

is in an incorrect order since is_x == 1 is FALSE for the first row.

My current ugly, ugly solution is to consider all possible arrangements then filter them down.

```
tibble(id=rep(df$id,factorial(nrow(df))),
         row_num = gtools::permutations(nrow(df),nrow(df)) %>% t() %>% as_tibble() %>% unlist %>% as.numeric,
         df_num = rep(1:factorial(nrow(df)),each=nrow(df))
         ) %>% 
    left_join(df, by = "id") %>%
    # identify the dfs which have correct order for first two rows
    mutate(incorrect_row = ifelse(row_num==2 & is_y==0 | row_num==1 & is_x==0,1,0)) %>%
    group_by(df_num) %>%
    mutate(incorrect_row = sum(incorrect_row)) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    # then filter
    filter(incorrect_row == 0) %>%
    # do same, choosing to keep later id in the third row
    group_by(row_num) %>%
    mutate(time_rank = rank(some_time)) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    mutate(time_rank = ifelse(row_num==3,time_rank,0),
           time_rank = ifelse(time_rank==max(time_rank),1,0)) %>%
    group_by(df_num) %>%
    mutate(time_rank = sum(time_rank)) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    filter(time_rank == 1) %>%
    # if more than one possibility, just choose the first
    filter(df_num == min(df_num)) %>%
    select(id,row_num)
```

However, in practice this solution is too slow. Is there a simpler, faster way to do this?
Hope this made sense, many thanks!

Comment: This seems very convoluted, to be candid. While it's feasible to find a precise ordering for _these three rows_, an informed answer will also consider a larger dataset and all of the rules/constraints that would go into this. Part of me wonders if there is either a better way to do this, and/or wonder why this seems necessary at all.

Comment: Can you add the desired output with a larger example dataset? Im not sure what you want and how your constraints work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataset is only a 3 by 4 tibble as stated, you can use this function below to achieve what you want:

##### 1. Run your code to create sample data

Note in my version I have changed the `=` to `<-`, it's not a big deal - just trying to align with mainstream R tradition.

```
df <- tibble(id = letters[1:3],
            some_time = c(3,1,2),
            is_x = c(1,0,1),
            is_y = c(0,1,0)
)
```

##### 2. Create a function `sort_some_time()` tailored to your goal

```
sort_some_time <- function(df){

  df$row_id <- seq.int(nrow(df))                    # note 1
  
  if (df[1, "is_x"] == 1 & df[2, "is_y"] == 1) {    # note 2
    
    df <<- df[order(df$some_time,      
                    decreasing = FALSE), ]          # note 3
    
    print("The data frame has been sorted.")        # note 4
    
  } else {
    is_x_outcome <- df[1, "is_x"] == 1              # note 5
    is_y_outcome <- df[2, "is_y"] == 1
    
    print(paste0("is_x is ", is_x_outcome, "; is_y is ", is_y_outcome))
  }                                                 # note 6
}
```

Notes:

1. Create a new variable `row_id`, which simply record the row numbers.
2. Create the condition as you stated (*only if when the first row is TRUE for **is_x**, AND the second row is TRUE for **is_y***).
3. If step 2 is TRUE, then sort the tibble by **some_time**.
4. Print a reminder to you when sorting is finished.
5. Record the logical results for **is_x** and **is_y** similar from step 2.
6. If step 2 is FALSE, then print out the logical results to remind you which one (or both) failed to pass the test.

##### 3. Let's create a dummy tibble that doesn't match your requirement

```
df_test <- tibble(id = letters[1:3],
                  some_time = c(3,1,2),
                  is_x = c(0,0,0),
                  is_y = c(0,0,0)
)
```

Run the `sort_some_time()` again, what did you see this time?

```
sort_some_time(df_test)
```

Hope this is helpful.